# Prove that $2^{n+1} = \Theta(2^n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I need to prove that $2^{n+1} = \Theta(2^n)$?

To do this, I need to show that there are positive constants $c_1,c_2$ such that

$$c_1 2^n \le 2^{n + 1} \le c_2 2^n$$ 
...for all sufficiently large $n$.

To find $c_2$, I know that I just need to find $O(2^n)$ which I have done below:

$$
\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n}=\frac{2 \cdot {2^n}}{2^n} = 2
$$

Therefore, $c_2 = 2$.

Can anybody tell me how to find $c_1$?

Comment: Note that
$$
\frac{2^{2n}}{2^n} = 2^{2n - n} = 2^n \neq 2
$$
However, 
$$
\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n} = 2^{(n+1) - n} = 2
$$

Comment: For $c_1$... how about $c_1 = 1$?

Comment: Where did you get 1 from?

Comment: I fixed the original question.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several choices available, but here's a hint: What number, when multiplied to $2^n$, will give you $2^{n+1}$?

Comment: That would be 2, right?  Though I already found 2 as my $C_2$.

Comment: Yes indeed it would. It's okay, though: $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be the same.

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused.  Can you provide reasoning to the logic here?  Why did you want to take a number multiplied by $2^n$ to get $2^{n+1}$?

Comment: Well, to find a $c_1$ such that $c_1 2^n \leq 2^{n+1}$, it certainly suffices if we find a $c_1$ such that $c_1 2^n = 2^{n+1}$. It may not make sense to try this all the time, but sometimes it works.

Comment: @Ken I am afraid there is no other option here than to *address the basic mistake in the question*, more explicitely than what you are doing now.

Comment: Ah OK gotcha, that makes sense!  In the original answer, you said that there are several choices available.  Can you explain how I could find another answer if I wanted?

Comment: Sure. Once you've found $c_1 = 2$ as something that achieves equality, other choices of $c_1$ which are less than $2$ (but still positive) would give you something less than $2 \cdot 2^n = f(n)$.

Comment: @Did I see what you're talking about, but Omnomnomnom seems to have addressed it. For my part, I was just happy to get back to asymptotic basics. ^_^

Comment: @Ken Sorry to insist but comments are transient, only answers are meant to stay, hence you definitely should address the question *in your answer*.